# PayPal payments

Tags: paypal, payment

I am trying to build a website where there will be different stores. A customer can come and order from any store he/she like. for example:

**In order 1:**

Customer1 buys a pair of shoe from Store1 for $70

Customer1 buys a shirt from Store2 for $30

**In order 2:**

Customer2 buys a pant from Store1 $50

For both stores (Store1 and Store2) I have an agreement that I will get 10% commission on an order.

***So on order 1***

I will get $7 from Store1 and $3 from Store2

Store1 will get $63
Store2 will get $27

Now can someone please tell me how to impletement this through PayPal.

Also will PayPal transfer all the $ amount to my and Store's bank account?

Regards,
AM

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to calculate all of the payments as necessary within your solution, but then you can use the [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) to process the split payment.  Specifically, you'll want to setup a [chained payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/?mark=chained%20payment).

If you are using PHP this [class library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make those API calls very quick and easy for you.

Comment: Thanks so much Andrew. If you can please tell me one last thing that do Store1 and Store2 need to have account on PayPal? Or their share of $ amount will be transferred directly to their bank accounts.

Comment: They will need PayPal accounts, and can then transfer the money to their bank from there.